# Is there a magic class function that can get a class constructor to take arguments like an associative array?

Tags: php, class, function, magic-methods

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
<?
    $addr = array("city" => $city, 
        "streetname" => $streetname,
        "housenumber" => $housenumber);

    $address = new address($addr);
?>
```

This just seems slightly redundant to me. Could I write the address to class to take this constructor?

```
<?
    $address = new address("city" => $city, 
        "streetname" => $streetname,
        "housenumber" => $housenumber);
?>
```

*(Yes I know I could create the array between the parenthesis of the constructor, I'm just curious)*

Comment: Thanks god this isn't Objective-C so you cannot do that. Note: this is a personal opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is reminiscent of an idea called [named parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) (seen in Python, Objective-C and C#), which PHP unfortunately doesn't support, nor do its developers plan to add support for anytime.